# Importing R.layout.main - Android

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application that will be using images and so I am working being able to grab an image and display it.  Though when I put in `setContentView(R.layout.main);` It tells me that `main` does not exist but offer to put into the layout file or `R.java`.  When trying to place it into the file and save the `R.java` files tells me it reverted it right back to the original purpose, why is that?

Comment: do you have file main.xml in your res/layout folder and are there any errors in your resource files? if so R.java is not generated

Comment: No I only have my activity_main.xml

Comment: then it should be setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Comment: @Raghunandan ha I just realized that :3  But hey I have this...`(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gimg1)` it does the same thing with the gimg1, not to sure what that is suppose to be?

Comment: that is initializing your imageview

Comment: Oh so I need to import my image viewer and give it the id gimg1?

Comment: check the edit in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments you said you have `activity_main.xml` and not `main.xml`

So change to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

ALso if you have imported R.java remove the same. Make sure there are no errors in your resource files. Clean and build.

If you have a imageview in activity_main.xml with id `gimg1`  then

```
  ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gimg1);
```

and import

```
  import android.widget.ImageView;
```

Its the same to initialize if you have others view's in your xml

Comment: `img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gimg1); ` is what I am using, should I not use this?

Comment: @DavidBiga its fine if you have a imageview in xml with id gigm1. if you are confused http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: whats the difference from using img to ImageView iv?

Comment: @DavidBiga its just the name. you can name it to whatever you like myimage ,yourimage or whatever. this is just like variable declaration in java. But it is better to follow naming convention and name it so that you don't get confused later if you want to debug

Comment: What I mean is that img is a type and ImageView is a seperate type right?

Comment: img is of type `ImageView`. img is a variable and `ImageView` is the type

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38109/discussion-between-david-biga-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 1):

`R.java` file is generated automatically, you can't edit it. In your case tyr to clean your project via `Project->Clean`

Comment: Ya I tried that, I just realized that my .xml file is activity_main.xml.